# can not use Cordova API in the sample project

Tags: javascript, cordova

I run the Cordova sample project and wanted to test the Cordova API, however, seems like can not use the API even though the cordova.js is embedded in the index.html. here's the code

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            notification.all();
        </script>
```

while in the index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        //
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the evheyent. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        alert('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

var notification={

   all:function (){alert(navigator.connection.type);}

}
```

**the error is "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined "**

Comment: Take a look at @mentat answer. And check also your cordova version: the call to connection has changed after 2.3.0 (is now the way you used it), so if you have an older version, you also have to update your code

Comment: the point is i can not use any API, even device.name. and actually i wait for the deviceready event, i attach the whole js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you posted your code after my other answer, instead of changing my previous post, I am writing a new answer.

Javascript is asynchronous, so while your app.initialize() call is executed, your notification.all() call is also executed, before deviceready is fired. In any case, your initialize call only adds the listener for deviceready, then you call your all() function, still before getting deviceready probably.

Comment: does it mean that if I can access the api within the anonymous function?

Comment: like:<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            console.log(navigator.connection.type);
        }, false);
    </script>

Comment: thx, it works!~ i think i need to get back to the fundamental of JS